# SwiftUI dictionary reference element strangeness

Tags: swift, swiftui

In a typical Swift app, I can have a dictionary, and write some code like this:

```
let e = dict[key]!
e.foo = "x"
```

And the element will be updated in the dictionary as expected.

However, this does not seem to work in SwiftUI!

Assuming in `userContext` we have a `Dictionary<Person>` (`Person` is a class), the following code works and updates the dictionary as expected:

```
self.userContext.dict[self.id]!.foo = "1234"
```

That is, in the debugger, I see this:

```
po self.userContext.dict
// dict[self.id].foo is "1234" as expected
```

(`userContext` is a @EnvironmentObject class with a dictionary inside it)

But this code does not update the dictionary in `userContext`:

```
var e = self.userContext.dict[self.id]!
e.foo = "1234"
```

```
po self.userContext.dict
// dict[self.id].foo is the old value, not "1234"
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's inside dictionary? What do you mean by and how do you detect "does not update the dictionary"?

Comment: Is it a struct as a dictionary value? If it so, you copied a struct by `var e = ...` and then modify a copy, not original value by reference.

Comment: Inside the dictionary is a class with a few string and int properties. The code above is exactly what I did (with variables renamed to fit). I'll update the question with what I mean by "does not update the dictionary".